# how to make proper default props with single objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, default, react-props

I have this code:

```
  const setup = (props: SchemaModalProps = { isOpen: false, onClose: () => { }, row: {}, onSchemaChange: () => { }, updateSchema: () => { }, hasPermission: false }) => {
    const wrapper: any = mount(<SchemaModal {...props} />);
    const driver = new SchemaModalDriver(wrapper);
    return driver;
  };
```

and when I call the setup function I need to specify the inner object items like so:

```
 const driver = setup({ isOpen: true, row: someTriggerConfiguration, onClose: () => { }, onSchemaChange: () => { }, updateSchema: () => { }, hasPermission: true });
```

how can I rewrite the code in such a way that if I do `setup({isOpen:false})` it will only overwrite the isOpen and not the rest of them ( use their default values).

Comment: Shouldn't this work? I don't really see the problem here. You have specified default values, so you should be fine doing it the way you are doing it. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: @Gh05d the current implementation will overwrite the entire `SchemaModalProps`, not just supplied property of it. So with `setup({isOpen:false})`  the `SchemaModalProps.onClose`, `SchemaModalProps.row`, etc will be `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on previous questions I found this to work best:

```
  const setup = ({ isOpen = false, onClose = () => { }, row = {}, onInfoChange = () => { }, hasPermission = false }) => {
    const props: TriggerInfoModalProps = { isOpen, onClose, row, onInfoChange, hasPermission }
    const wrapper: any = mount(<TriggerInfoModal {...props} />);
    const driver = new TriggerInfoModalDriver(wrapper);
    return driver;
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can destructure the props object and declare the function like below:

```
const setup = ({
  isOpen = false,
  onClose = () => {},
  row = {},
  onSchemaChange = () => {},
  updateSchema = () => {},
  hasPermission = false
}: SchemaModalProps) => {
  /**
   * Your code
   */
  return <></>;
};
```

Now `setup({isOpen:false})` will only override the isOpen property.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmUCuAHGBeGAKA3gWACgYYBLCAeRXjAxgDMBDAGwQBpDjwBhJkBWrAEoMAPhg4AvuyIwATiADutSdM5gAysAAW8ALYMuWhmADm8AcPRiVHGKgAmDKPE079F0eKm2jEAArwsrpkECTgtIws8IQSAFwwrnoMALIgjkx+8igQlta2APQAVIW2MIUwAJogSLIwoPbRMmX5tqCQIEzwAHS8JliJ+qnpmSDZgrayiDU0ANwxcwSECMgouGSU1PFQskjwEoJAA

Comment: yeah but notice I use ...props inside the wrapper, how will that work?

Comment: You have to make all the properties optional in `SchemaModalProps`.

Comment: [This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoIBYQLZwLID2AJnADYAKUBADgM7IDeAsAFDLLC0Dy1EIA-AC5kAIwIFSEOCADcrdgRABhUgVoQhyaQE85bZFQDumnXoUh0WXEozSA5huGn5yAK7USkSzjgmQul1tacmhsTlpgRU0xCSlZVgBfVgRFWjBkdTB3ZABeZAAKZn1OHj5c5HhSdQAaF0UVNRQ8-IBKXIA+RgTa-SNyhm66i0wfG3smgraczoGe9ndPCG9cctaOrrnkIJCoMNoIxXLK9UThZfxiMkoaWimZlwB6AConl2Qn5ABNAlcoZBSiBA3k8Hi4UiA0shqFQ6P0SrwQNVkPVVDUDARDEjFOcxiAHEiFnAvCNcEjtqFwpEQAkzP9UrEAHSqOz5aE3FouKAQLJQEDIPQ01isTLuQrwvjCMBQVwQBIclgi6iFcm7SmKSXS2XyxVi7gIwRSmVkuDBCn7KkamVyoA) should work.

Comment: If the property in `SchemaModalProps` is not optional then you have to pass all the required parameters, else it will throw an error.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoIBYQLZwLID2AJnADYAKUBADgM7IDeAsAFDLLC0Dy1EIAXMgBGBAqQhwQAblbsCIAMKkCtCIMkBPGW2RUA7upBbZyeeiy4FGSQHM1yTdvYBXaiUjmccQ8Z3Xa5NDYnLTA8oIiYhLSrAC+rAjytGDIqmCuyAC8yAAUzDqcPHxZyPCkqgA0JvJKKijZOQCUWQB8jLFVOvolDB3VIJ6W1iB2JU2t7Z0ubnAemF5jzZltvVPI-oFQwbSh8iVlqnGCg-jEZJQ0tEsrJgD0AFT3Jsj3yACaBM5QyIlEEM-3W4mRIgZLIahUOg9Qq8EAVUyKZSVXQEPTwszzIa2CDw1zuCAneEbIIhMIgWJOH5JKIAOmUNhyEMujRMUAg6SgIGQ2gprFYaVceRhfEEYCgzhxyGe7BlNSR9iay1WUp0Mpl+kEAG0ALrw6VqjEWOBWbGCcbLSYqtVqvGzAmY7y5a6W-Uy4lbUnhZBiiWu2IslgC6hC7iw0XiiD+-nswUMd3bXYCb0RqOBmPBhjCgQ+yXxz1JnP+oA

Comment: In the above example, I made the properties as required, and hence the bottom three function call will throw type error. Because I am not passing all the required properties.

Comment: @Alexander you can create the props object and pass in SchemaModal as props. Another way would be to pass the props one by one to SchemaModal like: `<SchemaModal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} .../>` since you already have those variables in your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign()` to combine two objects. This way only supplied new values will override default.

```
const setup = (props: SchemaModalProps) =>
{
  SchemaModalProps = Object.assign({
    isOpen: false,
    onClose: () => { },
    row: {},
    onSchemaChange: () => { },
    updateSchema: () => { },
    hasPermission: false
  }, SchemaModalProps || {});
  const wrapper: any = mount(<SchemaModal {...props} />);
  const driver = new SchemaModalDriver(wrapper);
  return driver;
};
```

Comment: umm SchemaModalProps is the type not the object itself.